# add base url before field text content

Tags: media, navigation

I have a text field used to enter a code (like 1111). This code is linked to a file (image) hosted in another server.

When a user displays this content type, I want to automatically display 3 things :

*the field content with the code (1111 for exemple) (I know how to do it)

- a picture whose url will always be : www.url.com/FIELD_CONTENT.jpg (www.url.com/1111.jpg)
- a link to the picture

Is it possible to do that ?

D8 but i can create a D7 website if needed.

Comment: Can you describe this question more clearly? How many pages do you want? What do you want to put in each page? It would be help if you draw a picture for your idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can render your image with a render array like this:

```
$a = array('#theme' => 'image',
        '#uri' => 'http://www.url.com/'.FIELD_CONTENT.'.jpg',
        '#alt' => 'Whatever',
    );
```

If you want that to be the content of an A tag (the link to press), render the link like this:

```
Link::createFromRoute($a, routename)->toString()
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: I think it's that what I want. My problem is that i'm not a developer and I really don't know where to put this code :(

Comment: You may try to add calculated fields to your content type for the link and the image, I am unsure here. Actually, I don't think you can do it without developing code (in a module or a theme). Most simple approach could be to override your content_type.html.twig template.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<?php print base_path().'yourimage.jpg'; ?>`

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!common.inc/function/base_path/8.2.x